# Importing CSV into MySQL and

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, mysql-workbench

I'm very new to using MySQL but have been tasked with creating a database to hold a considerable amount of client data.

The biggest issues I'm having is around normalization and how to import data to ensure it meets normalization rules. Obviously I could put everything into one big table and hope for the best but from anything I've read it will cause considerable problems down the road.

How should I embark on importing data that takes the following form (not actual data but form will be the same just more rows and more columns)

```
Unique Reg Num |Promotion  |Advert  |Characteristics
---------------|-----------|--------|----------------
123            |20% Off    |Aug 15  |Green;Blue;Purple
124            |10% Off    |Sep 14  |Purple;Red;Green
125            |20% Off    |Aug 15  |Green;Blue;Purple
126            |10% Off    |Sep 14  |Purple;Red;Green
```

So Promotion and Advert columns should be normalized and have separate tables (this is a many to one relationship I think) linked back to **Unique Reg Num** however the main issue is how to sort the Characteristics column. (I'll set up separate threads if needed for other questions)

I have several columns like the Characteristics column with delimited data. How should I upload this to a database so that data can be queried using these columns?

I could expand the rows for each delimited piece of data which would give me 3 rows of data for **Unique Reg Num** 123 (just using the sample table above). However, if I have another column with multiple characteristics, say 3 countries (Germany;France;Italy) then the number of rows trebles to 9 rows of data for **Unique Reg Num** 123.

I really have no idea how to begin to tackle this issue other than creating a big table.

I'm using MySQL 6.3, with MySQL Workbench. Currently set up in Win 7 for testing but will set actual database up on Windows Server 2012.

If I've left out any relevant info please let me know and I'll update the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `Characteristics` data is the epitome of unnormalized data.  You should try to obtain your data such that it is not in CSV format.  Doing a little more work now will pay off later.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the feedback. Could you expand on this a little bit? I'm completely along your lines of thinking e.g. more work now so that I have something that works in the long-term. How should I go about collecting this data so it will be more beneficial/ easier to work with?

Comment: Instead of `Green;Blue;Purple` being in a single row, you should have _three_ records, with each color appearing on one record.  Even this would not be ideal, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. If I then add another characteristic column say **characteristic_2** that has lets say 3 countries `Germany; France; Belgium`. This will mean my expanded data will have 9 rows instead of 3 being uploaded. Is this best practice? From here I will need to normalize (which I'm unsure of) but will open another thread to ask a question on this.

Comment: Avoid CSV in your tables.  Each of the records you gave above should be 3 records.  Yes, you have other normalization problems, but this one is bigger.

Comment: I would love to avoid csv but not overly familiar with other formats such as json and xml. also creating a user interface in php to upload data doesn't really work as the data needs to be batch uploaded. If I'm to avoid csv what other format should i be using?

Comment: I will post an answer showing you what your data should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your data should ideally look like.  I would split your sample table into two tables, one for promotion information and the other for characteristics:

**promotions**

```
Unique Reg Num |Promotion  |Advert
---------------|-----------|--------
123            |20% Off    |Aug 15
124            |10% Off    |Sep 14
125            |20% Off    |Aug 15
126            |10% Off    |Sep 14
```

**characteristics**

```
Unique Reg Num |Characteristic
---------------|----------------
123            | Green
123            | Blue
123            | Purple
124            | Purple
124            | Red
124            | Green
125            | Green
125            | Blue
125            | Purple
126            | Purple
126            | Red
126            | Green
```

These tables are fairly normalized, probably sufficient for your use case.  The challenge you face is in getting rid of that CSV data.